# Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules can't update Scope

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

The problem is basically that I was trying to update an already existing "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules" resource in Azure, but I got a: "Scope can't be updated (Bad Request)" Error.

What I did was to upload an ARM to update an already existing resource hoping that I could change the scope because I created a new AppInisghts, but It threw the error above.

I'm prety sure that the answer is that this kind of resources can't have their scopes updated. But why? "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts" Can do this :(

After researching a little bit I found this issue to some related documentation for migrating alerts https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/108608

Just wanted to be sure that I'm not able to update the scope and If that's true warn everybody with this post so they don't lose time searching for a solution (Because I didn't find anything claryfying in the official docs)

Thanks everybody.

PD: I'm sure that deleting the resource and creating it again would do the trick but It's not something I can do right now.

ARM code that you could use to test my problem:

- Prerequisite: have an existing resource with scope setted

  ```
    {
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
  "apiVersion": "2022-08-01-preview",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {
    "tagName1": "tagValue1",
    "tagName2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "kind": "string",
  "identity": {
    "type": "string",
    "userAssignedIdentities": {}
  },
  "properties": {
    "actions": {
      "actionGroups": [ "string" ],
      "customProperties": {}
    },
    "scopes": [ PUT NEW SCOPE HERE ],
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried in simple Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/scheduled-query-rules/update?view=rest-monitor-2021-08-01&tabs=HTTP)

Simple rest api eliminates the uncertainty caused by arm template

[image]

re-produce the same error message, I think it's a build-in feature.
It is recommended that you directly change the name of the alert and redeploy a new alert.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought.... worst think is that I didn't find it explicitly in any documentation, I appreciate that, I'll, mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the existed code in ARM, you need to follow below steps as it is not possible to update the `scope` property directly once the deployment is done.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-modes) for the relevant functionality.

> If the resource already exists in the resource group and its settings are unchanged, no operation is taken for that resource. If you change the property values for a resource, the resource is updated with those new values.

> If you try to update the location or type or scope of an existing resource, the deployment fails with an error. Instead, deploy a new resource with the location or type that you need.

But the above functionality is not suited for your environment as you mentioned this statement.

> I'm sure that deleting the resource and creating it again would do the trick but It's not something I can do right now.

***Alternative approach to this is using `export template` option under the resource.***

To achieve it, first I've deployed an insight scheduled query rule with scope as virtual machine resource ID and the deployment was succeeded as shown below.

[image]

Now go to this deployed resource in Portal and visit `Automation >> Export Template` as shown below.

Refer [Export Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal) MS Doc.

[image]

Once the relevant Json template has generated, click on `Deploy` option and it redirects you to the `custom deployment` page. Now choose `Edit template` option on the top of the page and add below code with modified scope (`workspace ID`) as shown below.

```bash
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "metricAlerts_mylatalertj_name": {
            "defaultValue": "mylatalertj",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "workspace_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/newwsj",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "actiongroups_newact_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/newact",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts",
            "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
            "name": "[parameters('metricAlerts_mylatalertj_name')]",
            "location": "global",
            "tags": {
                "Reason": "Repro",
                "CreatedDate": "2/26/2024 8:08:20 AM",
                "CreatedBy": "NA",
                "OwningTeam": "NA"
            },
            "properties": {
                "description": "This is a metric alert",
                "severity": 3,
                "enabled": true,
                "scopes": [
                    "[parameters('workspace_externalid')]"
                ],
                "evaluationFrequency": "PT1M",
                "windowSize": "PT5M",
                "criteria": {
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "threshold": 0,
                            "name": "1st criterion",
                            "metricName": "<Metric Name>", //As per your requirement
                            "operator": "GreaterThan",
                            "timeAggregation": "Average",
                            "criterionType": "StaticThresholdCriterion"
                        }
                    ],
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria"
                },
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "actionGroupId": "[parameters('actiongroups_newact_externalid')]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After applying the modifications, click on `Save` and proceed to `Review + create,` then select `Create`. This will initiate the deployment of an updated resource with the existing configuration by changing a new `scope` property and value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but, and correct me if I'm wrong. Isn't your solution based on a metricAlert? In fact metricAlerts allow to change scope however you want, via portal and via ARM. My problem is with "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules" specifically, with this ones even if you go to the portal and try to edit scope manually you'll see a greyed out "edit scope". Maybe I'm missing something from your answer but I see only metricAlert on your images.

Comment: Just like metric alerts, you can try for scheduled query rules and it will work via Portal custom template. Can you try once? @jaumecen

Comment: I will update with scheduled query rule as well. @jaumecen

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself clearly on the original question, but my goal here is to update the actual resource, If it can't be done that's okey, I would like to know why tho with a "metricAlert" you are able and why "scheduledqueryrule" no (if you don't believe me go to the portal and try to edit both of those resources and you'll see that it's greyed out for "scheduledqueryrule". I appreciate a lot your help @jahnavi.

Comment: It hasn't solved the problem unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried the same functionality for scheduled query rule? @jaumecen

Comment: Yep I get an error with "Scope can not be updated" on the deployment details.